# How to Check Particular UItextFiled Starting with WhiteSpace

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hi i just working of Validation of `UITextFiled` For checking that it Starting with WhiteSpace. For Example I am Enter City name `New York` In UITextFild like Bellow Image:-

[image]

as above `TextFiled`  Contain 6 blank space Before `New York`. so i want to check that User can not Enter Add white-space Before Word but it allow to Enterd black space of Sentence between two word.

I am using Bellow code for checking white-space.

```
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSRange range =[txtCityName.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespace]; 

if(range.location != NSNotFound )
{
    NSLog(@"hi ==%@",Whitespace Found);

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"hi ==%@",Whitespace Not Found);
}
```

Above Code Check Full `TextFiled` Text contain white-space or not, But I want to check only Starting of Sentence and also Check After end Of sentence it contain white-space or not.

Comment: Can't you just correct the sentence after the user finished entering? You could then just take the complete string and delete all the white space before and after the sentence easily

Comment: you want to remove all the spaces which are placed before and after the string or just you want to know?

Comment: as par Pratik answer it's something Going Current. user can't enter whitespace befor starting sentence. so i am using this UITextfild method of delegate `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and also `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` then my issue fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put below delegate method of textfiled. use below code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

try this user cannot insert space at starting of sentance

Comment: thank you Pratik for answered my question it working for check Starting of word whitespace but how to check after sentance of whitescpace

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with

```
 NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

& if you want to remove it from your string , you need to work on following

```
 <NEW STRING> = [<STRING_CONTAINS WHITESPACE> stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
 NSLog("String without white space = %@",NEW STRING);
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: thank's for reply Foram i know your puted Code it if i use this it remove all whitespace but i need only starting remove

Comment: your are right and your Solution also usefull but as compere with Pratik answer it's much better user cant enter whitespace befor starting sentance and i am not accept your both answer so i just give you 1+ for helping me Foram Sorry :)